# Can't get only 5 terms to display in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, slice

So im trying to display only **5 random child terms** in a list items that links to the term link. Im pretty close but I can't seem to only display 5.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms( 'types' );

    echo '<ul>';

    // shuffle!
    shuffle( $terms );

    // slice the array
    array_slice($terms, 0, 4);

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

        // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
        if ( 0 == $term->parent ) {
            continue;
        }

        // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>'; 
?>
```

I'm trying to use `array_slice` after shuffle, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the `array_slice` result into a variable e.g `$terms` like this

```
   $terms = array_slice($terms, 0, 4);

   var_dump($terms); //see you have 5 elements
```

Comment: care to give me an example using my code above? because I already have ```$terms = get_terms( 'types' );``` at the top

Comment: In my example `array_slice` overrides your previous `$terms` variable from `get_terms()`. If you don't want to override `$terms`-variable use a new variable e.g. `$sliced = array_slice($terms, 0, 4);` and then in the *foreach* use `foreach( $sliced as $term) {...}`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @LucasSantos Did you understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: but then I wouldn't be able to use my terms? I tried to just use that line of code under my $terms and it just displayed 3 terms for some reason.

Comment: If you `var_dump($terms)` directly after `get_terms($types)` and it shows you only 3 terms then you have not more then 3 terms of the given critera `$types`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @pbaldauf is suggesting you assign your current `array_slice()` function to a variable.

Comment: @LucasSantos. Just assign the `$array_slice()` function to a variable of your choice. Your code is fine. I think this question can be closed now.